# Solve this puzzle. I created for my friend for FUN :)

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle, pattern, calculation-puzzle

My friend is very good at puzzles. so i thought of creating one by myself and try to see if he can solve. Finally I succeeded and he gave up.
Interested people can try.

Hint: use all four arithmetic operations to get the sequence or logic

[image]

Comment: Hey! Welcome to Puzzling.SE. If you want a free badge you can take a tour here https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour :D

Comment: Is the 0 required in front of the 3 at the top of the leftmost triangle, or can I just treat it as a 3?

Comment: Yes. we need 0 for consistency in the logic.

Comment: Please give the answer or atleast some other hint.

Comment: It's a combination of multiply and again (add,subtract,multiply and division)

Comment: @uday, no arithmetic operation would produce a leading zero.

Answer (score 4):

Solution:

> [image: Solution]

Please let me know if you see any logic that was not correct.

Comment: For all the downvoters on my original post, please be advised that my answer was at least as much of a pattern as this answer.

Comment: Why is there a zero before the three? I understand that you had to show that it was an addition, but if that was the case, then we actually should have somehow got a "03" in the multiplication, and THEN done "0 + 3 = 3" to get the answer. More to the point, the first figure should've had a 2 digit number, since otherwise, the pattern is arbitrary.